# jQuery and Z-index issue

Tags: jquery, css

Im creating a simple image gallery. And I mean simple:

```
 <div id="outerdiv" style="width:600px;height:400px; background:#ccc;padding:50px;">
  <div id="theGallery">
    <div class="thumbnailDiv" id="tn1">
      <div style="position: absolute;">
        <img id="1" src="pic1.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="galleryButtonLeft"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I want to slide the image left so other images can appear when galleryButtonLeft is clicked. Heres my jQuery:

```
    $(function () {
    $(".galleryButtonLeft").mousedown(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#theGallery").animate({
      marginLeft: "-=300px"
       }, 1000);
      }).click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
     });});
```

And the CSS:

```
       .galleryButtonLeft
         {
        height:130px;
           width:40px;
         border:#996663 solid 1px;
         background:#e9cbad;
        z-index:30;
      }
```

The gallery slides to the left but its only hidden behind the `galleryButtonleft` div and not behind the `outerdiv` div portion to the left of my button. The `z-index` for the gallery is lower than all other `z-indexes`. So how do i hide `theGallery` so it doesnt show on the `outerdiv` div except for the current images to the right of the galleryButtonLeft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `overflow: hidden` on the parent container.  Then when the element leaves the bounds of the parent it will be hidden.

In addition, don't animate the entire gallery, just the `img` or it's wrapper.

**EDIT:**

Based on comments, here is an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6rHC2/3/

A wrapper was added with fixed size and `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Hi James. Thanks for responding. If you're saying place overflow:hidden on "outerdiv" I tried that before and it didnt work.

Comment: "theGallery" is the wrapper. "theGallery" will contain all my images but show only 3 at a time. I want to scroll "theGallery" left so the next set of images can appear.

Comment: It would likely be on `theGallery`.  Something like this  http://jsfiddle.net/6rHC2/2/

Comment: Okay, I see a little better what you're trying to do.  You will probably need an additional wrapper around `theGallery` which will have `overflow: hidden` and a fixed size.  You will also need to remove your button from the gallery so it stays still.

Comment: Thanks James. I need to do some tweaking, but this definitely has me on the right path.